# API TOKEN AUTHENTICATION in expressJS?

Tags: uber-api

https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication

I have to access resources on behalf of an Uber users? How can I do same in ExpressJS?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [API wrapper for Node, e.g. node-uber](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber). In case you need a working sample, check out my [GitHub project](https://github.com/agraebe/Take-Me-Home-Now).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package like [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) to make those request for you.